# How to hide and show element before submit form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to hide and show element before submit form using javascript ?

When i press button i want to show `id="loading"` and hide `id="sub"` before submit form ?

I test this code, i will show `id="loading"` and hide `id="sub"` but not submit form.

How can i do that ?

```
<form id="myForm" name="send_ask" action="xxx.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="12345" style=" display: none;">
    <button id="sub">Send</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
</form>
<div id="loading" style=" display: none;">WAIT</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         $("#sub").hide(),
         $("#loading").show(),
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});


</script>
```

Comment: Avoid click handlers for forms as they will not work for keyboard submitting. Attach the logic to your submit handler.

Comment: you have to manually submit your form via `$('#myForm').sumbit()`. This is missing in your click-function

Comment: @empiric: That will just go recursive (and do nothing with the current code, because of the return false).

Comment: right, i oversaw the second handler. So adding the function in the submit-handler (perhaps with `preventDefault()`) would be better, I agree with your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `$.ajax()` and use `beforeSend` & `complete`. Example:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        data: $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").show()
        },
        complete: function(data){
            $("#loading").hide()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to use `click` event, can use `submit` event as I updated!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.post` parameters are wrong. The right ones are

```
$.post(url, data, function(result){.. run some code on complete .. }, dataType);
```

So you need to run the show/hide logic either in the complete callback or before the post. A better way would be to attach the handler to the submit function instead of button click.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {

    $("#sub").hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    $.post(this.action, $(':input', this).serializeArray(), function(info){ 
        $("#result").html(info); 
    });

    clearInput();

    return false;

});
```

Comment: You use this instead of yours. It's a merge between the two handlers you have. And it doesn't submit twice, note the return fasle